# Shopping Cart has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a very simple shopping cart example using the has_many through association.

I have a cart model:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cart_products
  has_many :products, :through => :cart_products
end
```

A cart_products model:

```
class CartProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end
```

And a products model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cart_products
  has_many :carts, :through => :cart_products
end
```

I have a cart controller that has a add function:

```
  def add
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

    if request.xhr?
      @cart_product = @cart.add(params[:id])
      render :action => "add"
    else
      render
    end
  end
```

And in the routes config file:

```
  resources :cart do
    post 'add'
  end
```

In the applications controller, I have an function to initialise the cart:

```
  def initialse_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
```

What I am unsure about is how do I pass the cart ID in the products controller?

I know you can do @cart.products. But how do you do the other way around?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need a cart ID in a products controller?

Comment: Because I need to pass the cart ID to the url on the product page. This is the error I get when I don't pass it: No route matches {:action=>"add", :controller=>"cart", :id=>"2"} missing required keys: [:cart_id]